# How to use two properties for a single property editor?

Tags: delphi, ide, custom-component, propertyeditor

Refer to [this prior question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944810/how-can-i-implement-my-own-custom-property-editor-for-all-instances-of-a-certain) combo of mine. It's describing how to create a property editor for the IDE.

I've created another property editor for a completely different purpose. In this case, it's a glyph character selector of type `String` (because it *could* contain more than one glyph character). Unlike my other one in mentioned question/answer, this one is very specific to a particular property on a particular `TCollectionItem` class of mine.

All is good, and I can invoke this property editor for this particular property. However, I have a dilemma. The property editor, by nature, is directly related to a font. The user may choose a character (glyph) from a particular font. My property editor has the facility to change the font, and browse the glyphs contained within that font.

This component of mine also has the facility to specify the font, in a separate `TFont` property. The problem arises when it comes to the combination of both my `Glyph` property and `Font` property being used in the very same property editor. When I invoke this editor for the `Glyph` property, it also needs to know the `Font` which it needs to use. On the contrary, when user chooses a font and glyph character in this editor, it also needs to update both the `Glyph` and `Font` properties.

Long story short, `PropertyB` depends on `PropertyA`. If `PropertyA` changes, then `PropertyB` will have an entirely different set of possible values. So, whatever editor I install in the IDE needs to allow the user to change *both* `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` at the same time.

How can I make a property editor have access to more than one property?

Comment: Can the down-voters please leave me an explanation? Even my 5 year old question got down-voted for once. I really feel unwelcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

Instead of a property editor, implement a component editor. Such a component editor will have access to the entire component, not just a single property.

### Solution 2

Wrap both of your properties inside of a dedicated `TPersistent` class, and then create a `TClassProperty` property editor for this class instead. The individual properties will not actually invoke a property editor. Instead, their parent `TPersistent` will invoke a combined property editor which has access to all the properties within this class. A good existing example is the `TFont` editor.

Comment: "*This situation is technically impossible by using just a single property editor for just your Glyph property. A single property can only invoke an editor for that single property. There is no way to make a property editor aware of other properties alongside the one you have*" - that is not true. For instance, a common example is a database component with `DataSet` and `Field` properties, where the `Field` editor lists available fields from the assigned `DataSet`. There is a standard property editor for that. It is not uncommon to write editors that can take multiple properties into account.

Comment: @Downvoter - explain? I assume the same person who deleted my other comment? Is my answer "not useful" because it's Jerry Dodge who posted it?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did flag a comment of yours for moderatation for being rude.

Comment: @Remy Not sure what was so rude about it, but thanks for your contribution. "Chatty", sure. But rude? Really? I consider whoever keeps downvoting everything I post rude, hence my other comment. Anyway, it's a shame this gets down-voted *after* I fix it.

Answer (score 3):

`TPropertyEditor` has a public `GetComponent()` method that you can use to access the object(s) whose property is currently being edited (multiple objects with the same property can be edited at the same time, if the property editor allows it). Then you will have access to all of the other properties in the same object(s).

That being said, if your editor displays a pop-up dialog for editing, it should be  implemented as a component editor instead of (or in addition to) a property editor. A property editor should *edit* only one property at a time, though it may have read-only dependancies on other properties.  For instance, a `Glyph` property editor that also *edits* the `Font` property, and vice versa, is not a good design. But a component editor that *edits* both is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I completely overlooked that because I assumed `GetComponent` returned a `TComponent` (and my property is actually in a `TCollectionItem`), but `GetComponent` actually returns a `TPersistent`.

Comment: Either way though, I ended up using `Solution 2` in my answer, essentially just like how the `TFont` editor works.